# Do I need to indent my code in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

You would think that this would be an easy question, but I can't find the answer anywhere. >_<

Will Ruby throw syntax errors if my code is indented incorrectly? For example, would code like this work?

```
if str.blank?
  str = "Hello World"
no_input = true
  end
```

Obviously, this is bad style and I should indent correctly regardless. I want to know whether I can rule it out as the cause of a bug during debugging sessions.

Comment: my manager says code is written for humans not machines..so yes

Comment: I went ahead and wrote the above code in a Ruby script, and it ran without complaining, so that means the Ruby parser is fine with whatever indentation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, it would work. Ruby only looks for the line breaks.

But since code readability is also very important, I'd say you should take care of whitespace if only for that sake.

Answer (score 12):

### Indentation is (Usually) a Stylistic Choice

In Ruby, indentation *per se* is not relevant, although the location of linebreaks and other whitespace may cause ambiguity for the parser or cause it to consider certain things as separate expressions when you didn't mean for them to be. Here-documents and multi-line strings are also areas where indentation will matter.

In all cases, the real question is "what does the parser see?" In your example, it should be functionally equivalent to the properly-indented code. However, if you *really* want to know what's going on under the hood, take a look at Ruby's [Ripper module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html) to see how your code is actually being parsed.

Comment: +1 Good to know that there are some gotcha's where indentation matters.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby is not whitespace sensitive. Your code, although not pretty, will work.

However: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/56039

```
irb(main):001:0> a = ( 4 + 5 )
=> 9
irb(main):002:0> a = ( 4
irb(main):003:1>       + 5 )
=> 5
irb(main):004:0> a = ( 4 +
irb(main):005:1*       5 )
=> 9
```

Comment: ruby is sensitive to linebreaks. This is technically a whitespace (in regex terms)

Comment: Are you serious, damn that's pedantic.

Comment: not entirely true.  Ruby 1.9 is sensitive to whitespace in some instances.    `x = -> (a,b) { a * b * 3 }` will not compile, `x = ->(a,b) { a * b * 3 }` will

Comment: Ruby *is* sensitive to whitespace, compare `m (6, 11)` and `m(6, 11)`.