# Is indentation obligatory in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, coding-style, indentation

I got some errors in Ruby on Rails' code, but I don't know if that's because it's not indented. Does Ruby code work without indentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation isn't as strict as it is in python. Your code should work fine if indentation is off, but may not be maintainable or readable to another developer.

Comment: Yeah, I know something about quality requirements in code. But I had that doubt.

Comment: It is not "not as strict"; it does not matter at all (unless for heredoc closing, block commenting, and `__END__`).

Answer (score 2):

With a project that's strictly Ruby, your indentation will not matter. [Here's a SO answer to the same question that has a good example of functioning Ruby code with poor indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052312/do-i-need-to-indent-my-code-in-ruby). If you're curious about proper indentation style in general, [Github's Ruby style guide](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby) will be a good reference for you.

Since you mentioned Rails specifically, I imagine you might be running into errors with your template code. If you're using a template like slim or jade (your views will have `.slim` or `.jade` or `.haml`), indentation can be important, and the lack of indentation can cause errors. For example,

```
h1 Example code

- @foos.each do |foo|
  p = foo
```

Is valid slim code, but

```
h1 Example code

 - @foos.each do |foo|
p = foo
```

will generate a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

As @sawa says, indentation is not obligatory **but** it is good practice as it allows your code to be much easier to read (for humans), which means it's far easier to catch any errors. According to the book [Eloquent Ruby](http://eloquentruby.com/) a sensible practice is to use ***two spaces per line*** for indentation since this is clearly an indent, but without using up too much room on the line. The book also advises not to use *tabs* since there is no universal length of a *tab*, so they can vary in length greatly. To see all this in action...

**Code without indentation:**

```
class Human
def laugh
puts "laugh"
end
def cry
puts "cry"
end
```

The code isn't quite right, but it's not immediately obvious where the error is.

**Code with indentation and sensible spacing:**

```
class Human
  def laugh
    puts "laugh"
  end

  def cry
    puts "cry"
  end
```

Here it's much easier to see that the `end` that should be aligned with the class opening is missing. In short, yes indent your code and also use sensible spacing (such as the space between the methods). It'll help you and any humans working with or reading your code.